# Is there fogbugz integration with Splunk, similar to the Jira integration?

Tags: jira, fogbugz, splunk

The Jira integration is mentioned in http://splunkbase.splunk.com/apps/All/3.x/Operations/Change_Management/app:Splunk+for+Jira

Answer (score 0):

I see that you can submit bugs to Fogbugz via HTTP Post.

In Splunk there is a feature called [Workflow actions](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Knowledge/CreateworkflowactionsinSplunkWeb).

And you could use this to [HTTP Post a bug to Fogbugz](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/5.0.1/Knowledge/CreateworkflowactionsinSplunkWeb#Set_up_a_POST_workflow_action) in response to certain event types or presence of certain fields.